# Devstack: There was an error submitting the form. Please try again. (when launching instance)

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, devstack, openstack-cinder

When i try to launch an instance on my devstack (kilo) from horizon dashboard i get a message "There was an error submitting the form. Please try again."

That problem exists only when i try to start instance from admin user(from demo user works well). Also I can make volume without errors. 
I am working in ubuntu 14.04.
I think that the problem is in cinder, because of this error in log:

> Cinder
>
> > ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault [req-6eb7575e-aaf5-4884-ac3d-bfefb31f833d 28ad1bada6134e23b2b7ade80c745771 54b3a044c5824f269938c8d3c3d5e6b0] Caught error: Entity '(<)class 'cinder.db.sqlalchemy.models.Snapshot'> has no property 'tenant_id'
>
> Horizon
>
> > 2015-06-29 08:14:12.535521   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinderclient/client.py", line 272, in request
> >     2015-06-29 08:14:12.535525     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body)
> >     2015-06-29 08:14:12.535530 ClientException: The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-f98235a2-f894-4a07-9aa2-ef3c5aa7e9ef)

Last week everything worked well.
I tried reinstaling devstac, reinstaling ubuntu... so maybe someone know whats the problem??? :-/

Comment: Try using the openstack CLI. You might get a useful error message.

Comment: I tried cli, and everything worked well. I think that the problem is bug in horizon (it doesnt provide tenant id to cinder). I git clone from main branch, and this is live project, it changes every day. I will try stable version (havana).

Comment: Actualy not havana,  kilo is the latest stable version.